Issue establishing AzureOpenAI Connection through VS Code Prompt Flow
I am currently running into an issue trying to establish an AzureOpenAI connection.
I have properly logged into my azure account using the "az login" command and am trying to establish a connection to my AzureOpenAI subscription through Microsoft's chat-basic flow found in their github.
I have appropriately replaced the "name" and "api_base" per below, and hit Create Connection. I receive an error in the terminal and no prompt comes up for me to enter my api_key:
AzureOpenAI connection
As well, I have colleagues who have entered the same credentials and they were able to successfully receive a prompt to enter their api_key.
Here is the error I receive:
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\_pf_vsc_connection.py", line 52, in upsert_connection
    upsert_connection_new(args)
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\_pf_vsc_connection.py", line 65, in upsert_connection_new
    connection = _upsert_connection_from_file(args.file)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_cli\_pf\_connection.py", line 224, in _upsert_connection_from_file
    existing_connection = _get_pf_client().connections.get(connection.name, raise_error=False)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\_telemetry\activity.py", line 265, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\operations\_local_azure_connection_operations.py", line 111, in get
    return self._get(name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\operations\_local_azure_connection_operations.py", line 130, in _get
    return ArmConnectionOperations._direct_get(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\azure\operations\_arm_connection_operations.py", line 62, in _direct_get
    return _Connection._from_core_connection(provider.get(name=name))
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\core\_connection_provider\_workspace_connection_provider.py", line 461, in get
    connection_dict = self._build_connection_dict(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\core\_connection_provider\_workspace_connection_provider.py", line 336, in _build_connection_dict
    rest_obj: WorkspaceConnectionPropertiesV2BasicResource = cls.open_url(
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\core\_connection_provider\_workspace_connection_provider.py", line 148, in open_url
    raise OpenURLFailedUserError(
promptflow.core._errors.OpenURLFailedUserError: Open url /subscriptions/<My Subscription Credentials>/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/<My Workspace>/connections/<My API Name>/listsecrets?api-version=2023-04-01-preview failed with status code: 401, action: listsecrets, reason: Unauthorized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\pfutil.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\_pf_vsc_main.py", line 37, in main
    operate_connection(args)
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\_pf_vsc_connection.py", line 29, in operate_connection
    upsert_connection(args)
  File "c:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\.vscode\extensions\prompt-flow.prompt-flow-1.20.0\pfutil\_pf_vsc_connection.py", line 58, in upsert_connection
    connection = ConnectionOperations().create_or_update(connection)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\_telemetry\activity.py", line 265, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\operations\_connection_operations.py", line 87, in create_or_update
    orm_object = connection._to_orm_object()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\entities\_connection.py", line 247, in _to_orm_object       
    secrets = self._validate_and_encrypt_secrets()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<USERFOLDER>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\promptflow\_sdk\entities\_connection.py", line 116, in _validate_and_encrypt_secrets
    raise ValidationException(
promptflow.exceptions.ValidationException: Connection '<My API Name>' secrets ['api_key'] value invalid, please fill them.

So I was just wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue and where I could troubleshoot this further?
I have tried reinstalling my anaconda and VS Code and all my prompt code extensions, making sure everything is up to date.

I had similar issues when running the VSCode prompt flow widget in VSCode. Turned out it was a issue with keyring. I solved it by running
pip install keyrings.alt

for more details, see: https://github.com/microsoft/promptflow/issues/373#issuecomment-1866264409
